# Fancy indexing with tuples

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tuples, slice

Say I have a 100x100 array in numpy, from this array I want to select 10 random blocks of (x*x)
pixels and change the values of these blocks simultaneously. What is the best way to index the slices for each block? An ideal solution would be something along the lines of the following, where the slices are taken between the pairs of tuples.

```
A = np.ones(100,100)
blockSize = 10

numBlocks = 15

blockCenter_Row = tuple(np.random.randint(blockSize,high=(100-blockSize),size=numBlocks))
blockCenter_Col = tuple(np.random.randint(blockSize,high=(100-blockSize),size=numBlocks))
rowLeft_Boundary = tuple((i-blockSize/2) for i in blockCenter_Row)
rowRight_Boundary = tuple((i+blockSize/2) for i in blockCenter_Row)
colLower_Boundary = tuple((i-blockSize/2) for i in blockCenter_Row)
colUpper_Boundary = tuple((i+blockSize/2) for i in blockCenter_Row)

for value in range(10):
    A[rowLeft_Boundary:rowRight_Boundary,colLower_Boundary:colUpper_Boundary] = value
```

Comment: How do you deal with the overlap of blocks?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "best way" here: less cumbersome to write, faster to index, faster to create the indices,...? Because apart from the missing indices on the `*_Boundary` variables in the last line, this seems to work fine.

Comment: I've made a bit of a mistake in this example, ideally the centers of the blocks should be calculated so that there is no overlap in the final implementation.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use `as_strided()` to do the trick, if the blocks can be overlaped.

```
import pylab as pl
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

blockSize = 10
numBlocks = 15
n = 100
a = np.zeros((n, n))

itemsize = a.dtype.itemsize
new_shape = n-blockSize+1, n-blockSize+1, blockSize, blockSize
new_stride = itemsize*n, itemsize, itemsize*n, itemsize
b = as_strided(a, shape=new_shape, strides=new_stride)

idx0 = np.random.randint(0, b.shape[0], numBlocks)
idx1 = np.random.randint(0, b.shape[1], numBlocks)

b[idx0, idx1, :, :] = np.random.rand(numBlocks, blockSize, blockSize)*3 + np.arange(numBlocks).reshape(-1, 1, 1)

pl.imshow(a, cmap="gray", interpolation="nearest")
```

here is the output:

[image]

Comment: +1 As a minor nitpick, it safer to do `new_stride = a.strides * 2`, which will work regardless of the memory layout of the original array.

Comment: This is one possible solution that works well for smaller arrays. However in the final application I have Ny and Nx of 1080 and 1920 respectively which results in arrays of ~5GB or so depending on the block size.

Comment: Did you try the code for 1080x1920 array? `as_strided()` creates a view not a copy. the memory this code use is: `numBlocks x blockSize x blockSize x sizeof(dtype)`.

Comment: Yeah. Anything over ~1000x1000 crashes when run.